# setting PATH in .cshrc has no effect

Tags: linux, shell, csh

In my .cshrc there are two lines:

```
setenv PATH /a/bin:$PATH
cd /a/
```

The result of

```
setenv
```

is

```
...
PATH=/a/bin:<original PATH>
...
```

The result of

```
ls -l /a/bin
```

is

```
-rwxr-x--x 1 evgeny evgeny 122 May 13 13:43 run_me
```

The result of

```
run_me
```

is

```
run_me: Command not found.
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becasue `tcsh` or `csh` uses the different syntax as `bash`. Are you sure than do you using csh-like shell? For sh-like shells (s.g. bash) you need add your commands into `.profile`.

Try the next into your `.cshrc`:

```
set path=(/a/bin $path)
```

and relog, or use

```
source .cshrc #for re-read the cshrc
rehash #reread avialable commands in the path
```

EDIT - test result

```
[me@orion]/home/me(135)> echo $0
-tcsh
[me@orion]/home/me(136)> mkdir a
[me@orion]/home/me(137)> cd a
[me@orion]/home/me/a(138)> echo 'echo "$0 here"' >run_me
[me@orion]/home/me/a(139)> chmod 755 run_me
[me@orion]/home/me/a(140)> cd
[me@orion]/home/me(141)> set path=($HOME/a $path)
[me@orion]/home/me(142)> rehash
[me@orion]/home/me(143)> run_me
/home/me/a/run_me here
```

Comment: It doesn't work either (guess the two commands give the same effect, which isn't the desired one). I do use tsch (echo $0 yields -tsch)

Comment: @Evgeny btw, you're the user `evgeny`? because the script hasn't read-bit, it has only 751. Other users as evgeny can't run the script. (the execute bit is not enough for the shell scripts).